# Objective - C: `self` not responding

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a cocos2d layer named `ChoosePlayer` and in `init` method I am adding a few sprite using `[self addChild:]`. Its plain and works right. But when I try to do the same in another method as given below, its not working:

```
-(void) avatarchanged {
    [self addChild:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"av1.png"]];
    [self runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(100, 100)]];
    NSLog(@"added new avatar");
}
```

The `[self runAction:]` is also not responding. So I guess its not the problem with sprite, but with the `self` itself.

In between the `init` and `avatarchanged`, what I am doing is showing a UIView on top of openGL View, perform some actions there and returning back as follows:

```
-(void) selectAvatar {
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    flowCoverView = [[[FlowCoverView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)] autorelease];
    flowCoverView.center = ccp(-80 + winSize.width / 2, 80 + winSize.height / 2);
    flowCoverView.delegate = self;
    flowCoverView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*(3.14/180));

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.window addSubview:flowCoverView];
}
```

When the necessary actions are performed, flowCoverView is removed as follows:

```
- (void)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view didSelect:(int)cover {
    selectedavat = cover;
    [flowCoverView removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"avatarchanged" object:nil];
}
```

The notification posted above invoked my `avatarchanged` method, where the `self` is not responding.

Edit: here is my `init` method:

```
-(id) init {
if( (self=[super init])) {
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    BG = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"opponent.jpg"];
    BG.scale *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * 1;
    BG.position = ccp(240,160);
    [self addChild:BG];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(avatarchanged) name:@"avatarchanged" object:nil];
}
return self;    
}
```

Note: In my project there is a bunch of global variables declared using `extern`, they might something to do with my problem, but am not sure.

Could someone please help me with this?

Edit 2:
changed `avatarchanged` as follows:

```
-(void) avatarchanged {
    if (self == nil) {
        NSLog(@"self is nil!!!!!!!!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"pheww.. its not nil");
    }

    if (self.isRunning) {
        NSLog(@"running");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not running");
    }

    [BG runAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1.0 angle:100.0]];
    [self addChild:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"av1.png"]];
    NSLog(@"added new avatar");
    [self runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(100, 100)]];
}
```

log shows as

```
2012-03-26 11:16:21.213 Funsip[1550:207] pheww.. its not nil
2012-03-26 11:16:21.214 Funsip[1550:207] running
2012-03-26 11:16:21.224 Funsip[1550:207] added new avatar
```

the BG's runAction is also not getting applied, but doing the same in `init` method works perfectly right.

Edit 3:
The FlowCoverView that I add is implemented with OpenGL calls internally. May be it could be causing conflicts with OpenGL states setup in cocos2d. But I dont know OpenGL to look for these sort of issues.
Here is the link to the page where I took the flowcoverview from http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html

Comment: where is `-(void) avatarchanged` declared ?

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working" and "is also not responding"? Does the NSLog happen?

Comment: Could you show your init method?

Comment: I havenot declared `avatarchanged` anywhere, but its getting invoked and I am getting `added new avatar` log.

in `avatarchanged`, `[self addchild]` doesnt add a image to my layer and `[self runction]` doesnt move my layer

Comment: Does your `avatarchanged` method get called, do you see the "added new avatar" log message? Also the `avatarchanged` method needs to take the notification object as a parameter. So it should be declared like this: `- (void)avatarchanged: (NSNotification *)note;`

Comment: In addObserver, I gave the selector as `@selector(avatarchanged)`, so the `NSNotification` parameter is not required. Anyways, the method is getting invoked and the log `added new avatar` is getting printed.

Comment: did you check if self is nil?

Comment: never had a thought that self could be nil... but i checked anyways and it is not. is `self` a variable where it could be `nil` or is it a `keyword` where it somehow points to the current object always?

Answer (score 2):

Is 'self' in running mode (self.isRunning) ? if not nothing much will happen from a cocos2d point of view. The isRunning mode is achieved when you add the ChoosePlayer instance to a running CCNode descendant. If you forgot to add it to a running node, it will be ignored in draws, actions, etc ...

Comment: great clue, I was damn sure that 'isRunning' would be false, but sadly it is not.. !!!

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28056

Comment: thx for the link... I havnt implemented `onExit` and `onEnter` in my class, but now I implemented those with corresponding `super` calls and tried, still not working..
and as said in that post I commented out my `self.isTouchEnabled=YES;` and touch methods, then also its not working.. !!